# Overweight construction equipment for weight restricted plaza

Tags: structural-analysis

We have to use our equipment on a elevated plaza that has a weight restriction of 2,400 lbs. per sq. ft. Each tire (4 total) carries a weight of 10,050 lbs. (1/4 of the gross weight of machine 40,200 lbs.)Each tire has a foot print of 2.1875 sq. ft. which equates to 4,594.29 lbs. per square feet. The weight is distributed equally to all 4 tires.
We are considering using 4' x 10' 1"thick steel deck to disperse the weight. There would only be 2 tires at any time on each piece of steel. Is there a calculation to determine what the weight of the 2 tires (20,100 lbs.)over the steel deck would be dispersed at per square foot?

Comment: What equipment? be specific. What make and model, and what are you doing with it?

Comment: And what is an elevated plaza? Got any pictures?

Comment: Use lighter equipment.

Comment: Could you describe the plaza more? I'm imagining stone slabs supported by pedestals at their corners to elevate them above a drainage space, like [this one](https://www.google.com/maps/@41.8798239,-87.6369664,3a,61.6y,281.68h,81.08t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sJSCUC2G0vFLPpOvG6OrXfg!2e0!6shttps:%2F%2Fstreetviewpixels-pa.googleapis.com%2Fv1%2Fthumbnail%3Fpanoid%3DJSCUC2G0vFLPpOvG6OrXfg%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D286.26932%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i16384!8i8192) near my office that is frequently damaged by contractors on lift equipment.

Answer (score 0):

One inch of steel plate compared to its 120-inch length will render the plate very flexible. Its deformation behavior will be affected by the rigidity of the material of the floor supporting it. Normaly, it will deform into a bowl shape and bend up and even possibly seperate from the slab of the plaza at the ends, distributing most of the load to the center.

On top of that, your heavy machinery will have dynamic loading that can be the critical load to address.

Yor best bet is coordinting with the design engineer and building department.